# Xamarin.Essentials SecureStorage not persisting in android after play store update

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.essentials

On my Xamarin.Forms app I'd like to persist user/token info upon play store update. On iOS it does work as expected, having the data persisted even after manual uninstall/reinstall.

I'm gone through all the initializations steps for Essentials on android in the MainActivity:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

       [...]
    }

    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

And the data is saved like this:

```
await SecureStorage.SetAsync("token", user.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken);
```

How can I achieve the same behaviour as in iOS in Android?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?tabs=android If you look at the very first tip it tells you why. You need to disable Auto Backup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this you need to add this to your manifest file

```
<application android:allowBackup="false" ... >
</application>
```

that disables auto backup. Here's a quick rundown on [Auto backup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup). You should be able to verify that it will solve the problem by deleting Google Drive, where it usually stores the backup.

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know asap!